# Converting a Drawable to a Bitmap to change the color of a Marker in Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, drawable, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm converting an old application from v1 to v2, and I'm having a problem with the color of my Marker icons. I have a basic, white icon, and It needs to be colorized.

In v1, I did it this way :

```
Drawable d = DrawableUtils.resizeImageToDrawable(
    MapViewFragment.mapviewActivity,
    Configuration.Display.getDrawableFix(i),
    Configuration.MapView.getWaypointIconWidth(),
    Configuration.MapView.getWaypointIconHeight());
d.setColorFilter(color, Mode.MULTIPLY);

overlay = new MyFplnFixListItimizedOverlay(d);
```

Since v2 Markers do not accept Drawables for their icons, I thought about converting the Drawable to a Bitmap, like this :

```
Drawable d = DrawableUtils.resizeImageToDrawable(
    MapViewFragment.mapviewActivity,
    Configuration.Display.getDrawableFix(i),
    Configuration.MapView.getWaypointIconWidth(),
    Configuration.MapView.getWaypointIconHeight());
d.setColorFilter(color, Mode.MULTIPLY);

Bitmap icon = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();

Marker marker = MapViewFragment.map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(point)
    .title(Integer.toString(fplnType))
    .visible(true)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)));
```

But for some reason, it's not working. The icons stay white. Anyone knows why ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, here's how I did it at the end of the day :

```
Drawable d = DrawableUtils.resizeImageToDrawable(
                    MapViewFragment.mapViewActivity,
                    Configuration.Display.getDrawableFix(i),
                    Configuration.MapView.getWaypointIconWidth(),
                    Configuration.MapView.getWaypointIconHeight());
d.setColorFilter(color, Mode.MULTIPLY);

Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(b);

int myColor = b.getPixel(0,0);
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(myColor, color);

Paint pnt = new Paint();
pnt.setColorFilter(filter);
myCanvas.drawBitmap(b,0,0,pnt);

Marker marker = MapViewFragment.map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(point)
    .title(Integer.toString(fplnType))
    .visible(true)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(b)));
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Did you had to handle OutOfMemoryExceptions?

Answer (score 1):

If your drawable is not defined in a XML, you can do it with this method:

```
protected Bitmap fromDrawable(final Drawable drawable, final int height, final int width) {
        final int widthDip = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(1, width, getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics());
            final int heightDip = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(1, width, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Note that if you need to do it from OUTSIDE an `Activity`, you'll also need to pass a `Context` (in order to call `context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()`). You also pass the `DisplayMetrics` object instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this DrawableUtils is doing, but you're casting it to a BitmapDrawable. Is it really a BitmapDrawable?

here's some code to extract a Bitmap out of any type of drawable:

```
Drawable d = // make sure it's not null
d.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
d.draw(c);
```

the idea is that you create a canvas on a mutable bitmap and draw that drawable on the canvas

**edit:**

I've just seen the @Analizer answer and yeah, my answer is good if you don't have the Drawable as a resource. But if you do, user his answer instead.

Comment: I'm not casting DrawableUtils to a Drawable, I'm just using it to resize the drawable to a certain size. Also, thank you for your advice, but I'm confused as to what I should put for "display" and "config".

Comment: sorry, I should have explain a bit more, and also there was a mistake (check updated code). The config can be any of the options from here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html and the display the options from here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html The display you can get the display metrics and I reckon it already pre-scale the Bitmap to the display, but you'll have to test this for yourself as it is just a guess of mine. But as you can see on the edit, you can just the construction without the display.

Comment: But what am I supposed to do next ? Should I directly use the Bitmap as the icon for my marker ? I've tried it and it's not working, the marker isn't showing.

Comment: it's been q few months since I did this code. I don't know. Try putting this Bitmap in a ImageView. This will test if the problem is the generated Bitmap or how you're setting the Bitmap to the marker.